# CentOS can not enter phpmyadmin

Tags: centos5

I am useing CentOS 5.5, mysql 5.1, php 5.3, phpmyadmin 3.4.5,
I have set my mysql password with

```
>mysql update mysql.user Password="mypassword" where User="root"
```

And in phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php

Do:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword';
```

Note: the 2 `password` are same.

```
service mysqld restart
service httpd restart
```

All is returned ok. Then in the phpmyadmin login panel, I type;

```
username: root
password: mypassword
```

Enter, It always refreshes the login panel, never login into the database page. No error hint.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem there is you've put a plaintext password in to a field that is supposed to hold an encrypted password!

Try the following from the MySQL command line:

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpass');`

and if you access it remotely don't forget:

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('newpass');`

followed by:

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

That will insert the password encrypted so it can be read, and then clear the privileges cache so it's read freshly again.